# Splitting sprites (texture atlases) into tiles with three.js

Tags: three.js, imagemagick

The goal is to create many thumbnails from a given set of pictures, assuming all thumbnails have same dimensions.

https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_ubiquity_test2 is a nice example showing the `texture.wrapS`/`texture.wrapT` + `texture.offset` approach, but it means cloning a texture for each thumbnail, that has performance implications. A question is: *how to reuse a single texture?*

Having the `16384x16384px` limit in mind, another aspect to cover is: *how to prepare multiple sprites, load corresponding textures and distribute them among tiles (thumbnails)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preparing the sprites

Assumptions:

- original assets have the same aspect ratio, e.g. `~1.485` (`2894x1949px`)
- we're about to render `128` thumbnails in the end
- `imagemagic` is installed
- `./assets/images/thumbnails/` is a working directory for manipulations
- `./assets/images/sprite-0.jpg`, ..., `./assets/images/sprite-<n>.jpg` will be actual sprites - horizontal atlases (single rows of tiles)

First off, let's define desired thumbnail dimensions. Since `three.js` requires each texture dimension to be a power of `2`, a height could be set to `256px`, making a width equal `380px`. This means `43` tiles per sprite (`43*380=16340`, where `16384` is a limit for the total width).

### Building a single sprite

1. Cleanup `./assets/images/thumbnails/original-selected/` and copy a portion of `43` original assets there.
2. Execute a set of **steps** listed below.
3. Rename a resulting `sprite.jpg` into `sprite-<iteration>.jpg`.

#### Steps

Generate small assets:

```
$ mogrify -path ./assets/images/thumbnails/small/ -resize 380x256 ./assets/images/thumbnails/original-selected/*.png
```

Build a sprite out of small assets:

```
$ convert +append ./assets/images/thumbnails/small/*.png ./assets/images/sprite.png
```

Note that the sprite now is `16340x256`, so it has to be resized to `16384x256` for
both dimensions to be a power of `2` (otherwise `three.js` will do that on the fly):

```
$ convert -resize 16384x256\! ./assets/images/sprite.png ./assets/images/sprite.png
```

Finally, convert the sprite to JPEG, reducing the size:

```
$ convert -quality 85 ./assets/images/sprite.png ./assets/images/sprite.jpg
```

## Loading textures and creating thumbnails

Tiling itself (setting the `geometry.faceVertexUvs` value) is inspired by https://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/sdg/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mappi-1/19147

```ts
import {Scene, Texture, TextureLoader, Vector2, PlaneGeometry, BufferGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial, Mesh} from 'three';

const thumbnailWidth = 380;
const thumbnailHeight = 256;
const thumbnailsCount = 128;
const spriteLength = 43;
const spriteUrlPattern = 'assets/images/sprite-<index>.jpg';
const scene = new Scene();
const loader = new TextureLoader();

loadAllTextures()
  .then(initializeAllThumbnails);

function loadAllTextures(): Promise<Texture[]> {
  const spritesCount = Math.ceil(thumbnailsCount / spriteLength);
  const singlePromises = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < spritesCount; i += 1) {
    singlePromises.push(loadSingleTexture(i));
  }

  return Promise.all(singlePromises);
}

function loadSingleTexture(index: number): Promise<Texture> {
  const url = spriteUrlPattern.replace('<index>', String(index));

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    loader.load(url, resolve);
  });
}

// Tiles are taken from different sprites,
// so thumbnail meshes are built using corresponding textures.
// E.g. given 128 tiles packed into 3 sprites,
// thumbnails 0..43 take the 1st texture, 44..86 - the 2nd one and so on.
function initializeAllThumbnails(allTextures: Texture[]) {
  const baseGeometry = new PlaneGeometry(thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight);
  const materials = allTextures.map((texture) => new MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
  }));

  for (let thumbnailIndex = 0; thumbnailIndex < thumbnailsCount; thumbnailIndex += 1) {
    const geometry = getThumbnailGeometry(thumbnailIndex, baseGeometry);
    const materialIndex = Math.floor(thumbnailIndex / spriteLength);
    const material = materials[materialIndex]; // could be cloned in here, if each material will need individual transformations, e.g. opacity
    const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
  }
}

function getThumbnailGeometry(thumbnailIndex: number, baseGeometry: PlaneGeometry): BufferGeometry {
  const tileWidth = 1 / spriteLength;
  const tileIndex = thumbnailIndex % spriteLength;
  const offset = tileIndex * tileWidth;

  // +---+---+---+
  // | 3 | . | 2 |
  // +---+---/---+
  // | . | / | . |
  // +---/---+---+
  // | 0 | . | 1 |
  // +---+---+---+
  const tile = [
    new Vector2(offset, 0),
    new Vector2(offset + tileWidth, 0),
    new Vector2(offset + tileWidth, 1),
    new Vector2(offset, 1),
  ];

  const plainGeometry = baseGeometry.clone();
  const bufferGeometry = new BufferGeometry();

  // a face consists of 2 triangles, coords defined counterclockwise
  plainGeometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [
    [tile[3], tile[0], tile[2]],
    [tile[0], tile[1], tile[2]],
  ];

  bufferGeometry.fromGeometry(plainGeometry);

  return bufferGeometry;
}
```

Comment: Why are all the solutions for this modifying the uvs of geometries? I've seen this numerous times, but no one considers that maybe the `Texture` class is not designed properly? It should be possible to create multiple textures using the same image, or some kind of `TextureWrapper`. That way you could have the same geometry (sprite) reused and uvs offset by an uniform.

Comment: @pailhead, I agree - using a `Texture` feels more appropriate. It would be great if sharing a single image could be possible.